# Reporting Services interactive conditional sorting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I would like to add a bool parameter to my report where option one sorts my bar chart based on the labels of my x-axis in ascending order and option two sorts the bar chart based on the values on the bars in descending order. How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use an IF

```
If @Parameter = 1
   begin
   ...SQL with sort ascending
   end
   else
   Begin
   ... SQL with sort descending
   End
```

Comment: How do I do that if I want to accomplish that client side?